# Install .desktop file with setup.py

Tags: python, linux, pip

I have a python application that is supposed to be launchable via GUI so it has to have a .desktop file in /usr/share/applications/. The application only supports Linux. Normally, pip installs all files in one directory but it is possible to specify other locations (e.g. the .desktop file) in the setup.py using data_files=[].

Is this considered to be good a solution in this case or is this something that should only happen in a distribution specific package (like .rpm/.deb/.ebuild)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me like a good approach but perhaps instead of placing the `.desktop` file in the system wide `/usr/share/applications/` folder, you could place the file in the users applications folder at `~/.local/share/applications`.

This would also not require elevated permissions to access the root owned `/user` directory and it's sub-directories.

Comment: However, you would probably need to provide the full path to the executable as your desktop shell might not show .desktop files which's Exec line cannot be `stat`ed. GNOME Shell does that.  So I think the question then is: How make setuptools replace the path in the `Exec` line of the .desktop file it installs?

Comment: @FrederickNord: You're right, although, the [docs](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) state that `Exec` may be specified *"with the name of the executable only"*. I think this is strange. As a workaround, the following works fine for me: `Exec=bash -c 'export PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin"; some-executable %U'` The benefit is, that the location of `some-executable` may in user's local tree *as well as* in the global path.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can define the install path of your `.desktop` in your `setup.py` script.

You can do that because you know where you want to install it, it is *not* distribution specific. It's loosely defined by the [Freedesktop Specififications](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/).

Usually, the desktop files are located in these directories:

- `/usr/share/applications`
- `/usr/local/share/applications`
- `~/.local/share/applications`

There is not really any reference stating that, but if you want to know more you can have a look at the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) and the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

So you know that you want to install in `share/applications`. But what about the **prefix** before that? The answer is that you, as a developer, don't have to care about that. It's up to the packager to decide.

So, here's how you do it in your `setup.py`.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name       = 'myapplication',
    version    = '0.1',
    packages   = ['myapplication'],
    data_files = [
        ('share/applications', ['data/org.myapplication.desktop']),
    ],
)
```

As you can see, the directory we give (`share/applications`) is **relative**. Quoting Pythons's [writing setup script](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files):

> If directory is a relative path, it is interpreted relative to the **installation prefix** (Python’s sys.prefix for pure-Python packages, sys.exec_prefix for packages that contain extension modules).

Thanks to that, when the packager sets the installation prefix (usually `/usr` or `/usr/local`), your desktop file will be installed in the correct location.

---

BTW, talking about desktop files, be sure to read the part about the [naming conventions](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#basic-format):

> ... should follow the "reverse DNS" convention, e.g. org.example.FooViewer.desktop.

BTW2, contrary to what has been said on this page, there's no need for an absolute path in the `Exec` line of your file. Look at the files installed on your system, almost nobody do that.

```
grep Exec= /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
```